# read_excel 'expecting numeric' ..... and value is numeric

Tags: r, excel

I didn't find an answer to this question, so hopefully this is the place to get some help on this.

I am reading in many Excel files contained in .zip files. Each .zip that I have has about 40 excel files that I want to read. I am trying to create a list of data frames, but encounter an error on reading some files based on file content.

This is the read statment, inside a for loop:

```
    library(readxl)
    df[[i]] <- read_excel(xls_lst[i],
                      skip = 4,
                      col_names = FALSE,
                      na = "n/a",
                      col_types = data_types)
```

data_types has these values :
    `> data_types
    [1] "text"    "numeric" "numeric" "numeric" "numeric" "numeric" "numeric"`

which is correct for this file.

The read_excel statement works well on some files, but returns warning message on others :

```
In read_xlsx_(path, sheet, col_names = col_names, col_types = col_types,... :
[54, 7]: expecting numeric: got '9999.990000'
```

Well, the value '9999.99000' looks like a numeric to me.
When I open the Excel file that creates this warning, the file indeed shows these values, and also shows that the column is formatted as text in Excel.
When I change the column formatting to numeric, re-save the Excel sheet, then the data is read in correctly.

However, I have several hundreds of these files to read ... how can `read_excel` ignore the column format indicated by Excel, and instead use the `col_type` defintion that I supply in the calling statement ?

Thanks,

Comment: Can you try to read the same file (that gives the warning) using `read.csv`

Comment: I would try to read in without setting `col_types = data_types`. After reading in it should be easier to encode the columns correctly.

Comment: @akrun : yes, if I save the excel file as .csv file, then I can read the associated .csv file correctly. Not sure how that helps, unless there is a utility that globally converts ~800 .xlsx files to .csv format ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to build a toy example.

My xlsx file contains:

```
3   1
3   3
4   4
5   5
7   '999
6   3
```

Reading in it your way:

```
data_types<-c("numeric","numeric")
a<-read_excel("aa.xlsx",
       col_names = FALSE,
       na = "n/a",
       col_types = data_types 
       )
Warning message:
In read_xlsx_(path, sheet, col_names = col_names, col_types = col_types,  :
[5, 2]: expecting numeric: got '999'
```

Reading in everything as `text`

```
data_types<-c("text","text")
dat<-read_excel("aa.xlsx",
          col_names = FALSE,
          na = "n/a",
          col_types = data_types
          )
```

And using `type.convert`:

```
dat[]<-lapply(dat, type.convert)
```

works at least for this simple example.

*Edited:

There was a mistake in the code.

*Edit in response to comment:

Another toy example demonstrating how you could apply `type.convert` to your data:

```
#list of data frames
l<-list()
l[[1]]<-data.frame(matrix(rep(as.character(1:5),2), ncol = 2), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
l<-rep(l,3)

#looping over your list to encode columns correctly:
for (i in 1: length(l)){ 
l[[i]][]<-lapply(l[[i]], type.convert)
}
```

There might be better solutions. But I think this should work.

Comment: thanks for this suggestion. I can see that it works on a single data frame .... but since I am trying to build a list of data frames, is there a syntax that works to do the `type.convert` ? Not knowing any better, I just tried things like : `df[[i]][] <- lapply (df[[i]], type.convert)` but that generates error messages such as : `Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : the first argument must be of mode character`

Comment: Have you read in everythings as `text`? I think for `type.convert` everything must be text.

Comment: OK @Alex ... it is working. took me a while to work through that, as I was doing several things with the data, grabbing some other information from the 4 header lines, and needed to go one by one to isolate the other problem that I was having .... `type.convert` apparently does not like to work on Posix date columns. I found another work around for that.      So, you have provided me a working solution. Thanks !

Comment: @community : this still seems like an '`unexpected feature`'  of `read_excel` that it does not actually have the capability to force `numeric` data types on a column of data read from excel, when all of the values in that column are, in fact, `numeric`. Not sure if that is worth exploring another day.

Comment: well, after a few painful errors uncovered, I discovered this twist :  the `lapply()` actually returns a list of lists, rather than a list of data frames. So, I need to find a way to retain the list of data frames structure & / or convert the output of the for loop with the `lapply()` command back to list of data frame structure. Some research required on my part about a good way to do that.

Comment: Sorry I missed something. You just have to add an extra pair of `[]` so that it looks this way `l[[i]] []<-lapply(l[[i]], type.convert)`. Then the data.frame structure is maintained. So you don't have to add an extra loop. I also added this to the answer above.